# Getting accessible markers in google maps in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, accessibility

I'm trying to get accessibility working on my markers/items/cluster using Google Maps SDK in iOS (Swift 3.0, XCode 8.1).

The accessibility inspector shows the "Traits" as "Button" but when highlighted, it actually shows the proper label (see screenshots).

[Marker NOT clicked/highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbbsn.png)

[Marker clicked/highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XARBt.png)

I'm trying to add code on the marker, cluster item, marker icon and even the marker iconView:

```
marker.accessibilityLabel = "marker Accessibility label"
marker.icon.accessibilityLabel = "marker icon accessibility label"
```

Along with setting "isAccessibilityElement" to true.

Does anyone have any experience getting Google Maps to be Accessible on iOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable accessibility for `GMSMapView` object.

```
mapsView.accessibilityElementsHidden = false
```

Refer :-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map

*Section - Accessibility*

Comment: Updated solution for this issue. I am new to this community and will follow practice as stated by you.

Comment: That is the spirit. Have a look here on how to improve the formatting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (Though Shree did that for you now.)

Comment: Upvotes for a descent answer in the right spirit coming in now... :-) Nice to see that happening. So much about being welcoming to a newbie.